# Generate a unique time-based id on a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to generate a unique id/timestamp based on the clock of the database server. This is not the main Id of the table, but it's in my interest that this value is unique for each row. This code is in a stored procedure that will be executed simultaneously by various processes running at the same time.

I've come up with this code but can't find a way to make it more elegant. As far as I've tested, the only way to make sure the other processes don't generate the same value on some other thread is by locking the table while doing a check exists.

```
DECLARE @CurrentRRN varchar(30)
SET @CurrentRRN = FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmssffffff')

IF(EXISTS(SELECT RRN FROM dbo.Numbering WITH (xlock, tablockx, holdlock) 
  WHERE RRN = @CurrentRRN)) BEGIN

  WHILE( EXISTS(SELECT RRN FROM dbo.Numbering WHERE RRN = @CurrentRRN) )
    BEGIN
        SET @CurrentRRN = FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmssffffff')
    END

END

INSERT INTO dbo.Numbering
(RRN)
Values
(@CurrentRRN)

print @CurrentRRN
```

Comment: Should that be a datetime2??? Maybe you should explain what could be the purpose?

Comment: "...will be executed simultaneously..." In that case, how can it be unique? If 2 records are inserted at the same time, it can't be unique, unless you do lock the table for the entire process - and that would only lead to slow inserts at best case, and deadlocks on worst case. Why would you want it unique anyway if you already have a primary key?

Comment: Why not use a uniqueidentifier (`NEWID()`)? These will be unique. If you also want some datetime (or datetime2) value, just add an additional column.

Comment: The reason is the customer was a 'numerical string id' generated from the date (their wording :P ), apart from the unique id (int) used on another table. So the 'Numbering' table is used to generate and keep track of this id. That's why I'm checking if it exists after generating it and generate a new one if it's already created by a parallel process. It's not going to be thousands of records per second, but multiple processes are going to access this procedure and I want to make sure there's not a duplicate.

Comment: First consider changing the `RRN` to have a sequence number for rows inserted at the "same" time, e.g. `yyyyMMddHHmmssfffffff-nn`. You might want to consider implementing a trigger to assign the values whenever an `insert` is executed for the table. It would capture the `SysDateTime`, get the maximum `RRN` value for the date/time (if any), increment the sequence number and update the table. Note that if the `insert` involves multiple rows then the trigger will need to assign suitable, presumably sequential, values to the rows, possibly ordered by some other column. And handle overflows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, read all the excellent advice from the comments and other answers about why you probably should do something different.

But, yes you can do this, and here's how.  Basically just replace the last few digits of the datetime2 with the values from a sequence.  The more digits you replace, the more rows you can insert at the same time without violating the unique constraint.  In the example below I'm replacing everything past the 10th of a second with the sequence value.  If you wanted to retain more digits of sub-second precision to store the actual clock time at which the insert was attempted, you would just reduce the maximum number of rows you can insert in a batch.  So up to you.

Here it is:

```
drop table if exists MyTableWithUniqueDatetime2

drop sequence if exists seq_ts_nanoseconds
go
create sequence seq_ts_nanoseconds
start with 0 
increment by 100
minvalue 0
maxvalue 99999900
cycle

go
create or alter function GetTimestamp(@ts datetime2, @ns int)
returns datetime2(7)
as
begin
 return  dateadd(ns,@ns, dateadd(ns,-(datepart(ns,@ts) % 100000),@ts))
end
go
create table MyTableWithUniqueDatetime2
(
  id bigint identity,
  a int,
  b int,
  ts datetime2(7) default dbo.GetTimestamp(sysdatetime(), (next value for seq_ts_nanoseconds)) unique

)
go
select sysdatetime()
insert into MyTableWithUniqueDatetime2 (a,b)
output inserted.*
select top (1000) 1,2
from sys.objects o, sys.columns c, sys.columns c2
```

Comment: Well, this will prevent worrying about locks, but also throws the nanoseconds accuracy out the window, but on the other hand, I mean, suppose you are inserting 300,000 rows - the first will get accurate time, but by the time you have inserted the 300,000th row to the database, your sequence now returns 3,000,000 - that's a million nano-seconds off. Not sure it matters that much but then again, basing a unique index on the time the row was inserted is a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: Yes.  But note that normal computers time share the CPUs with time slices in the millisecond range.  So measuring when a computer did something is only accurate to 3 or 4 decimal places.  If you were storing data generated by some super-accurate external device, the 100ns resolution of datetime2(7) might be meaningful, but for data generated with SYSDATETIME(), it's not.

Comment: That is one piece of the puzzle I wasn't aware of... thanks for the info!

Comment: I went with this solution, provides the simplest way of generating the unique id and keep a timestamp! I wasn't aware you could use the built in sequence like this so I learned a lot! Thank you!!!

Comment: I wasn't aware either, until you asked the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it.  Create a numerical `identity` column.  For the most part, that will keep track of the order of inserts (this gets a little tricky in multi-threaded environments, but it should be close enough).

Add another column, say `createdAt` with a default value of the timestamp.  You can make this a `datetime2` column for more precision.

If you really need a unique numerical value, I would suggest creating a computed column whose type is something like `decimal(38, 10)`.   It would have a structure something like this:    YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFFFFFF..  ("F" is for fractional seconds.)

Comment: The timestamp, doesn't matter how long or fractional you go, is still possible to get two exact values. I ended up going the route of the accepted answer, which is combine the timestamp with a sequence (similar to the identity column)

Comment: @DaniDaniDr . . . If you just want a unique column, use `identity` and declare it to be `unique`.

Answer (score 0):

hi tried a simple performance test using Sequence instead of Identiy.

with a 1000000 of rows, identity needs 20 s, sequence >50 s.

here my test:

```
drop sequence if exists seq_ts_nanoseconds
go
create sequence seq_ts_nanoseconds as int
start with 0 
increment by 1
minvalue 0
maxvalue 1000000
cycle


--drop table #t1
create table #t1
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    v nvarchar(50)
)

;with
tmp1 as
(
    select 0 c union all
    select t1.c+1
    from tmp1 t1
    where t1.c+1<1000000
)
insert #t1(v)
select t1.c
from tmp1 t1
option (maxrecursion 0)

------------------------

--drop table #t2
create table #t2
(
    id int,--identity(1,1),
    v nvarchar(50)
)

;with
tmp1 as
(
    select 0 c union all
    select t1.c+1
    from tmp1 t1
    where t1.c+1<1000000
)
insert #t2(id,v)
select next value for seq_ts_nanoseconds,
       --ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 0)),
       t1.c
from tmp1 t1
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

here a example online: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=34180889596d24d1237c1723f3746f71