# Why does my SQL Server trigger write two records with the same time stamp from different transactions?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-trigger, ormlite-servicestack

I have a SQL Server table with an integer `Status` column. My code updates the `Status` of a record and then, milliseconds later, updates it again to a different value.

This table has a trigger which inserts a record into a separate `History` table every time the `Status` value changes.

The `History` table has columns for:

1. `Id uniqueidentifier`: the PK value of the updated record (note: NOT a foreign key - we don't need referential integrity)
2. `Status int`: the new status value of the updated record
3. `TimeUtc DateTime2(7)`: the time the update occurred

An NLog log file shows us that we make the two separate database `UPDATE` calls at close, but different times. But when we look in the database afterwards, the `TimeUtc` value for the two history records are identical to the microsecond:

```
Id: CD83...  Status: 4  TimeUtc: 2020-3-20 16:14:26.6952631
Id: CD83...  Status: 5  TimeUtc: 2020-3-20 16:14:26.6952631
```

Why is this happening? To make this even more bizarre, sometimes, when we run concurrent code, two separate records will be updated at nearly the same time and all four history records will have the same timestamp.

```
Id: CD83...  Status: 4  TimeUtc: 2020-3-20 16:14:26.6952631
Id: CD83...  Status: 5  TimeUtc: 2020-3-20 16:14:26.6952631
Id: 06EA...  Status: 4  TimeUtc: 2020-3-20 16:14:26.6952631
Id: 06EA...  Status: 5  TimeUtc: 2020-3-20 16:14:26.6952631
```

We are using ServiceStack OrmLite to update the values and the docs tell me that each call is a separate transaction which (I thought) would produce two separate trigger events, but perhaps that's wrong. It looks like SQL Server is saving up trigger events and firing them all at once. Could ServiceStack OrmLite be batching the calls under the hood into a single transaction?

Here is the trigger definition. Let me know if more details are needed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ChangeStatus] 
ON [dbo].[TableWithStatus]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE    
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- On insert, or on update where status changed
    INSERT INTO History
        SELECT i.[Id], i.[Status], SYSUTCDATETIME()
        FROM Inserted i 
        LEFT JOIN Deleted d ON i.Id = d.Id
        WHERE i.[Status] IS NOT NULL 
          AND (d.[Status] IS NULL OR i.[Status] <> d.[Status])
END
GO
```

ADDENDUM:
I updated the History table with a fourth field (varchar) and update the Trigger to write @@SPID and CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID() to this field separated by a colon. Here's what I got:

[image: History table]

Every update was performed in the same session and a separate transaction, both of which are what I would have expected, but then it still does not explain why the records share the same time stamp.

Comment: Hmm, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysutcdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) states that the precision depends on the underlying Windows API and is limited. Maybe things just happen to fast for the next timestamp to be different from the previous.

Comment: Maybe you should also [edit] the question and explain what problems you face due to the duplicate timestamps. Maybe there are workarounds for that.

Comment: could you try storing the @@spid into the history table and see if the two calls are two separate sessions (and not a single one)?

Comment: I've run into similar problems with tracking history in our Key Management system. The only thing that seemed to work was pairing the timestamp with an integer `IDENTITY` column. The combination would tell which record was _really_ the first.

Comment: See answer here for an option of using a SEQUENCE to replace the last few (meaningless) digits of sub-milisecond precision. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459805/generate-a-unique-time-based-id-on-a-table-in-sql-server/51460731#51460731

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to [sticky bit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9661424/sticky-bit) and [lptr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12403612/lptr). It does appear that the operating system is the culprit.

According to [SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysutcdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> SQL Server obtains the date and time values by using the GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() Windows API. The accuracy depends on the computer hardware and version of Windows on which the instance of SQL Server is running. The precision of this API is fixed at 100 nanoseconds. The accuracy can be determined by using the GetSystemTimeAdjustment() Windows API.

[This long and complex article](http://www.windowstimestamp.com/description), however, does a better job at explaining why. I can't say I understand all of it, but the bottom line appears to be that SYSUTCDATETIME() uses an OS tool that reads a clock value which is not updated often enough to get the precision we were expecting. The article above refers to a typical machine updating its clock 64 times a second, which is not even millisecond accuracy. The article does indicate that there are ways to get more accurate results, especially with newer versions of Windows, but I cannot easily access those methods from a SQL query.

As long as we understand why it is happening we can live with the results.